# MutableList transformation

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, collections

I have a `SortedMap<String, MutableList<Double>>` type which I need to transform/map to `SortedMap<String, Double>`. The `MutableList<Double>` in the first type represents a list of expenses and now I want to add all of those up into a total and use the total instead. String object in both types remains the same.

Currently I have this implementation:

```
val sortedEntryMap = dateToEntriesMap.toSortedMap() // SortedMap<String, MutableList<Double>>
val dailyEntryList = mutableListOf<Pair<String, Double>>()
for ( dailyEntry in sortedEntryMap ) {
   var dailyTotal = 0.0
   for (entry in dailyEntry.value ) {
      dailyTotal += entry
   }
   dailyEntryList.add(Pair(dailyEntry.key, dailyTotal))
}
```

but I would like to have some cleaner (more Kotlin) implementation than this. Something along the lines of: `dailyEntryList = sortedEntryMap.map { something, something }` The map() method is probably not the one to use but I was just wandering if there is a way to do this in one line of code?

Comment: so what do you need `SortedMap<String, Double>` or `MutableList<Pair<String, Double>>`?

Comment: I need the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```
sortedEntryMap.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.sum() }
```

to get a map with the same keys and transformed values

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html

Comment: Niiiice! Thx! This is exactly what I was looking for :)